# How to mark spot as harvested/cleaned/removed/solved in analyzer?

Tags: no-mans-sky

After completely harvesting a (copper) mine this spot will still remain on my analyzer radar (PC-key <kbd>F</kbd>).
The same is true for the "rescued crashed part" or a "stone of wisdom" (not sure about the correct English game translation).

How can I mark this spots as already harvested, cleaned, solved, removed?
How can I make them disappear from my analyzer?

Comment: Most POIs clear on their own. Mines "regrow" to some degree, so they're a bit of an exception.